# Can't set values in second activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

So I'm making a simple application that just takes some information from the user i.e Name, address etc and puts it in the the textviews in the next activity but when I put in the values and move to the next activity there's nothing displayed in the TextViews.

Here's my first activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



public String Name;
public String Age; 
public String Address;
public String City;
public String phoneno;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 Name = name.getText().toString();
EditText Amge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.agee); 
 Age = Amge.getText().toString();
EditText Address2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
 Address = Address2.getText().toString();
EditText City2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
City = City2.getText().toString();

EditText phone2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
phoneno = phone2.getText().toString();

final ImageView D = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.done);
D.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, second.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);}}
```

Here's my second activity

```
public class second extends MainActivity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
 TextView N1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name1);
 N1.setText(Name);

 TextView A1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age1);
 A1.setText(Age);

 TextView Ad1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address1);
 Ad1.setText(Address);

 TextView C1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city1);
 C1.setText(City);

 TextView P1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone1);
 P1.setText(phoneno);}  
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

Here's my xml for the main activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context="com.example.randomtests.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="21dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="Please enter the required info"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/bar" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/agee"
    android:layout_below="@+id/agee"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/address"
    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/city"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/address"
    android:layout_below="@+id/address"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/city"
    android:textColor="#000000" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:hint="@string/namu"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/agee"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/age"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textColor="#000000" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/city"
    android:layout_below="@+id/city"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/phone"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/done"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/button" />
```

Here's my xml for the second activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/bg" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:textSize="33dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/yourinfo"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/info1"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/age1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name1"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/age1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/age1"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/city1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/address1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/address1"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/city1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/city1"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: please take some oop course ... setting non static fields in instance of base class will not set em in new instace of derived class ...

Comment: I have been programming for a while now but left it since 2 years. I used to do something similar to pass the values but I just can't remember. Please explain what I'm doing wrong code wise. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you declare your Intent , try sending your data with this

```
//this use key-value
intent.putExtra("USER_NAME" , "your string");
intent.putExtra("USER_AGE" , "your string");
```

and etc.

and to other Activity try use

```
 Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
 String userName = extra.getString("USER_NAME");
 String userAge = extra.getString("USER_AGE");
```

Comment: Still not working. The TextView  still doesn't display anything

Comment: @user2435339 use getExtras before setText ?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your `Intent` here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, second.class);
```

Try sending some data with it using `Extras` based on what view is being clicked on

For example:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, **Your String Here**);
```

And in the activity receiving the intent, use something like:

```
 String data  = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT);
```

To fetch the data from the intent